# Find $f'(0)$ if $f(x)=\int_{0}^{(\pi/2)+2\sin x}\sin (y+x\cos y)dy$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

The problem is as the following:

$f(x)=\int_{0}^{(\pi/2)+2sinx}\sin(y+xcosy)dy$.

Evaluate $f'(0)$.

I have tried several times, using several different approaches like fundamental theorem of calculus, total differential and chain rule in multi-variable calculus, but what I've tried were failed.

Thank you for providing clues.

Comment: Try using the [Leibniz Integral Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Answer (score 0):

May be, you could consider the integrand for small values of $x$
$$\sin (y+x \cos (y))=\sin (y)+x \cos ^2(y)+O\left(x^2\right)$$
$$I(y)=\int\sin (y+x \cos (y))\,dy=-\cos (y)+\frac{x}{4} (2 y+\sin (2 y))+O\left(x^2\right)$$
$$I(0)=-1$$
$$I\left(\frac{\pi }{2}+2 \sin (x)\right)\sim I\left(\frac{\pi }{2}+2 x\right)=\sin (2 x)+\frac{1}{4} x (4 x-\sin (4 x)+\pi )$$
$$I\left(\frac{\pi }{2}+2 \sin (x)\right)-I(0)\sim \sin (2 x)+\frac{1}{4} x (4 x-\sin (4 x)+\pi )+1$$
Now, Taylor series around $x=0$ to get
$$I\left(\frac{\pi }{2}+2 \sin (x)\right)-I(0)\sim 1+\left(2+\frac{\pi }{4}\right) x+O\left(x^3\right)$$